# How much memory is being garbage collected?

Tags: java, performance, garbage-collection, jvm, weblogic

I would like to know how to print JVM verbose log files to see how much memory is being garbage collected.

**Q1**: How to add garbage collection parameters to WebLogic server

**Q2**: How to add manual garbage collections in code level in Java?

**Q3**:  How to find Number of max/min http connections configured in the Weblogic server...

Please answer my set of question.
my application is very slow to resolve that I am searching for the answers to these questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*how to print JVM verbiage log files to see how much memory is garbage collecting?*
-This is answered by @Nikolay Kuznetsov here.I am reproducing the same for the sake of completeness.

```
-XX:PrintGCDetails 
-Xloggc:<filename>
-XX:+PrintGCDateStamps
-XX:+PrintTenuringDistribution
-XX:+PrintClassHistogramBeforeFullGC 
-XX:+PrintClassHistogramAfterFullGC
```

*how to add garbage collection parameters to web logic server and how to add manual garbage collections in code level in java*

For most of the application server, this is generally done in the startup batch files. Generally there is a `JAVA_OPTS` env varibale which is set with the JVM parameters. An example on windows would be :

```
set JAVA_OPTS= %JAVA_OPTS% -XX:PrintGCDetails -Xloggc:<filename>
```

Please check the Weblogic start up batch files and add this at appropriate place.

*how to find Number of max/min http connections configured in the weblogic server*
I would recommend to consult the relevant application server specific documentation. I could find [this link](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E13222_01/wls/docs81/perform/WLSTuning.html#1136287). Please check.

Comment: can i set the above parameter by using admin console..??

Comment: Not really. You access Admin console when the server is up and running whereas these values needs to be set before the server is started.

Comment: we can do the same in websphere like in below link    http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/websphere/library/techarticles/0706_sun/0706_sun.html so like wise am searching for weblogic sever.

Comment: Not sure if Weblogic offers similar UI, but I found [this link](http://www.togotutor.com/forums/weblogic/29-how-set-heap-size-weblogic.html). But you always use the [command line parameter](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E13222_01/wls/docs81/perform/JVMTuning.html#1109778).

Answer (score 1):

You can use following options:

```
-XX:PrintGCDetails 
-Xloggc:<filename>
-XX:+PrintGCDateStamps
-XX:+PrintTenuringDistribution
-XX:+PrintClassHistogramBeforeFullGC 
-XX:+PrintClassHistogramAfterFullGC
```